# doubly sub stochastic matrices

Tags: matrices

In a paper by Fan Ky he proves that if $a_1\geq a_2\geq...\geq a_n\geq 0$ and $b_1\geq b_2\geq...\geq 0$ and  if $p_{ij}$ are $n^2$ non-negative numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij}\leq 1$ for all $j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij}\leq 1$ for all $i$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^np_{ij}a_ib_j\leq\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$ and he proves in a very elegant way that:

$\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^np_{ij}b_j\leq \sum_{i=1}^k b_i$ for$1\leq k\leq n$.(3)

and then he says "By Abel's lemma, $a_i\geq a_{i+1}\geq 0$  and (3) imply

$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^np_{ij}a_ib_j\leq\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i$

Though (3) is good enough for my purpose I would be interested in this last step, because using Abel´s lemma I could just achieve $a_1$ on the RHS. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: the paper is "MAXIMUM PROPERTIES AND INEQUALITIES FOR .THE
EIGENVALUES OF COMPLETELY CONTINUOUS OPERATORS",http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063464/